# Best way to create the behavior of an extendable Enum in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, inner-classes, extends

I want to create something that resembles an extendable Enum (understanding extending Enums isn't possible in Java 6).

Here is what im trying to do:
I have many "Model" classes and each of these classes have a set of Fields that are to be associated with it. These Fields are used to index into Maps that contain representations of the data.

I need to be able to access the Fields from an Class OR instance obj as follows:

```
MyModel.Fields.SOME_FIELD #=> has string value of "diff-from-field-name"
```

or

```
myModel.Fields.SOME_FIELD #=> has string value of "diff-from-field-name"
```

I also need to be able to get a list of ALL the fields for Model

```
MyModel.Fields.getKeys() #=> List<String> of all the string values ("diff-from-field name")
```

When defining the "Fields" class for each Model, I would like to be able to keep the definition in the same file as the Model.

```
public class MyModel {
    public static final Fields extends BaseFields { 
        public static final String SOME_FIELD = "diff-from-field-name";
        public static final String FOO = "bar";
    }

    public Fields Fields = new Fields();

    // Implement MyModel logic
}
```

I also want to have OtherModel extends MyModel and beable to inherit the Fields from MyModel.Fields and then add its own Fields on top if it ..

```
public class OtherModel extends MyModel {
   public static final class Fields extends MyModel.Fields { 
        public static final String CAT = "feline";
        ....
```

Which woulds allow

```
OtherModel.Fields.CAT #=> feline
OtherModel.Fields.SOME_FIELD #=> diff-from-field-name
OtherModel.Fields.FOO #=> bar
OtherModel.Fields.getKeys() #=> 3 ["feline", "diff-from-field-name", "bar"]
```

I am trying to make the definition of the "Fields" in the models as clean and simple as possible as a variety of developers will be building out these "Model" objects.

Thanks

Comment: Not to sound rude or cliche, but if the designers of the language decided that enums shouldn't be able to be extended, you may want to search for why they made that decision, or you may find yourself falling into a trap they specifically set developers up to avoid.

Comment: Thats fair -- the reason I mentioned "enum" is because its the closest construct i know of in Java that matches my use case.

Comment: (damn time limits) Thats fair - I mentioned "enum" because its the closest construct i know of that resembles the behavior I need fo my use case. 

I need a list of valid keys used to index a Map, and this list must be 1) accessible to developers via intellisense (and as a bonus I get compile time checks) and 2) have the list of keys accessible as a list so computations can be done in bulk. 

Forcing devs to 1) known the string values to index into the Map or manually enter all static variables for bulk processing of data, leads to an _extremely_ brittle code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution using reflection that seems to work -- I haven't gone through the full gamut of testing, this was more me just fooling around seeing what possible options I have.

ActiveField : Java Class which all other "Fields" Classes (which will be inner classes in my Model classes) will extend. This has a non-static method "getKeys()" which looks at "this's" class, and pulled a list of all the Fields from it. It then checks a few things like Modifiers, Field Type and Casing, to ensure that it only looks at Fields that match my convention: all "field keys" must be "public static final" of type String, and the field name must be all UPPERCASE.

```
public class ActiveField {
private final String key;

protected ActiveField() {
    this.key = null;
}

public ActiveField(String key) {
    System.out.println(key);
    if (key == null) {
        this.key = "key:unknown";
    } else {
        this.key = key;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return this.key;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getKeys() {
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    Class cls;
    try {
        cls = Class.forName(this.getClass().getName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return keys;
    }

    Field fieldList[] = cls.getFields();

    for (Field fld : fieldList) {
        int mod = fld.getModifiers();

        // Only look at public static final fields
        if(!Modifier.isPublic(mod) || !Modifier.isStatic(mod) || !Modifier.isFinal(mod)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Only look at String fields
        if(!String.class.equals(fld.getType())) {
            continue;
        }

        // Only look at upper case fields
        if(!fld.getName().toUpperCase().equals(fld.getName())) {
            continue;
        }

        // Get the value of the field
        String value = null;
        try {
            value = StringUtils.stripToNull((String) fld.get(this));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            continue;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            continue;
        }

        // Do not add duplicate or null keys, or previously added named fields
        if(value == null || names.contains(fld.getName()) || keys.contains(value)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Success! Add key to key list
        keys.add(value);
        // Add field named to process field names list
        names.add(fld.getName());

    }

    return keys;
}

public int size() {
    return getKeys().size();
} 
}
```

Then in my "Model" classes (which are fancy wrappers around a Map, which can be indexed using the Fields fields)

public class ActiveResource {
    /**
     * Base fields for modeling ActiveResource objs - All classes that inherit from
         * ActiveResource should have these fields/values (unless overridden)
     */
    public static class Fields extends ActiveField {
        public static final String CREATED_AT = "node:created";
        public static final String LAST_MODIFIED_AT = "node:lastModified";
    }

```
public static final Fields Fields = new Fields();

    ... other model specific stuff ...
```

}

I can then make a class Foo which extends my ActiveResource class

```
public class Foo extends ActiveResource {

public static class Fields extends ActiveResource.Fields {
    public static final String FILE_REFERENCE = "fileReference";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
}

public static final Fields Fields = new Fields();

    ... other Foo specific stuff ...
```

Now, I can do the following:

```
ActiveResource ar = new ActiveResource().
Foo foo = new Foo();

ar.Fields.size() #=> 2
foo.Fields.size() #=> 4

ar.Fields.getKeys() #=> ["fileReference", "type", "node:created", "node:lastModified"]
foo.Fields.getKeys() #=> ["node:created", "node:lastModified"]


ar.Fields.CREATED_AT #=> "node:created"
foo.Fields.CREATED_AT #=> "node:created"
foo.Fields.TYPE #=> "type"
etc.
```

I can also access the Fields as a static field off my Model objects

```
Foo.Fields.size(); Foo.Fields.getKeys(); Foo.Fields.CREATED_AT; Foo.Fields.FILE_REFERENCE;
```

So far this looks like a pretty nice solution, that will require minimal instruction for building out new Models.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to be able to access the Fields from an Class OR instance obj as follows:

```
  MyModel.Fields.SOME_FIELD #=> has string value of "diff-from-field-name"
```

That is not possible in Java unless you use a real `enum` or `SOME_FIELD` is a real field.  In either case, the "enum" is not extensible.

The best you can do in Java 6 is to model the enumeration as mapping from String names to `int` values.  That is extensible, but the mapping from names to values incurs a runtime cost ... and the possibility that your code will use a name that is not a member of the enumeration.

---

The reason that `enum` types in Java are not extensible is that the extended `enum` would break the implicit invariants of the original `enum` and (as a result) could not be substitutable.

Comment: +1: I can think of a few other alternatives, but they're progressively more and more horrific.

Comment: Stephen, What I am trying to do is creating/exposing a list of keys that are subject to compile-time checks, and whose names can be "human friendly" while the actual keys will not. Having a static class with static final strings (as they key/values) gets me nearly there -- as it allow these fields to be inherited, however I am unable to get a list of all the "keys" (or static final Strings) in the class, without manually loading them into an array, etc.

Comment: Also - I understand you cannot do this using java enums. Thats why I said "best way to create the BEHAVIOR of an extensible enum" .. I want to figure out how to model it using "normal" java classes. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried out some code trying to do what you've just described and it was *really* cumbersome.

If you have a `Fields` static inner class somewhere in a model class like this:

```
public class Model {

  public static class Fields {

    public static final String CAT = "cat";
    protected static final List<String> KEYS = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
      KEYS.add(CAT);
    }

    protected Fields() {}

    public static List<String> getKeys() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(KEYS);
    }
  }
}
```

and you extend this class like this:

```
public class ExtendedModel extends Model {

  public static class ExtendedFields extend Model.Fields {

    public static final String DOG = "dog";

    static {
      KEYS.add(DOG);
    }

    protected ExtendedFields() {}
  }
}
```

then its just wrong. If you call `Model.Fields.getKeys()` you'd get what you expect: `[cat]`, but if you call `ExtendedModel.ExtendedFields.getKeys()` you'd get the same: `[cat]`, no `dog`. The reason: `getKeys()` is a static member of `Model.Fields` calling `ExtendedModel.ExtendedFields.getKeys()` is *wrong* because you really call `Model.Fields.getKeys()` there.

So you either operate with instance methods or create a static `getKeys()` method in all of your Fields subclasses, which is so wrong I can't even describe.

---

Maybe you can create a `Field` interface which your clients can implement and plug into your model(s).

```
public interface Field {
  String value();
}

public class Model {

  public static Field CAT = new Field() { 
    @Override public String value() {
      return "cat";
    }
  };

  protected final List<Field> fields = new ArrayList();

  public Model() {
    fields.add(CAT);
  }

  public List<Field> fields() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(fields);
  }      
}

public class ExtendedModel extends Model {

  public static Field DOG= new Field() { 
    @Override public String value() {
      return "dog";
    }
  };

  public ExtendedModel() {
    fields.add(DOG);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you really need a generated enumeration of fields.  If you are going to generate a `enum` of a list the fields based on a model, why not generate a class which lists all the fields and their types? i.e. its not much harder to generate classes than staticly or dynamically generated enums and it much more efficient, flexible, and compiler friendly.

So you could generate from a model something like

```
class BaseClass { // with BaseField
    String field;
    int number;
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass { // with OtherFields
    String otherField;
    long counter;
}
```

Is there a real benefit to inventing your own type system?

Comment: Because it provides 1) compile-time checks to ensure developers are using the correct keys to index into the underlying data model and 2)  lists of all keys could be generated automatically (via getKeys()) and iterated over, removing the need to create brittle code where I explicitly have to list out all keys individually 3) and allows me to maintain the list of keys in a single place (per model). (Ex. I wouldnt have to define all the keys manually and then also manually load them into a List that drives getKeys())

Comment: Just to provide a little more context, these "Fields" will be used to index into the Model's underlying data Map as well as into HttpRequest ParameterMaps.  

`myModel.get(myModel.Fields.CREATED_AT) #=> this removes the need for dev to know that the actual key into the Map is "node:created" or some other esoteric key.`  

`myModel.put(myModel.Fields.FOO, slingHttpRequest.getParameter(myModel.Fields.FOO));`  

`for(String k : myModel.Fields.getKeys()) { myModel.put(k, slingHttpRequest.getParameter(k)) }`

Comment: 1) using classes is a more compiler friendly way to define fields, 2) You can use getFeilds() to get the public fields of a class, however if you use generated code, you usually don't need this. i.e. you generate the code for anything you would iterate over. 3) You can use a single source model with generate your classes/enums

Comment: You can use reflection to populate a class `for(Field f: obj.getClass().getFields()) f.set(obj, slingHttpRequest.getParameter(f.getName()));`

Comment: I did something like this, i had a big post with code samples but it didnt get saved :( ..

Answer (score 0):

Curses - For some reason my very lengthy response with the solution i came up with did not post.

I will just give a cursory overview and if anyone wants more detail I can re-post when I have more time/patience.

I made a java class (called ActiveField) from which all the inner Fields inherit. 
Each of the inner field classes have a series of fields defined:

```
public static class Fields extends ActiveField {  
     public static final String KEY = "key_value";  
}
```

In the ActiveRecord class i have a non-static method `getKeys()` which uses reflection to look at the all the fields on `this`, iterates through, gets their values and returns them as a List.

It seems to be working quite well - let me know if you are interested in more complete code samples.